# How to adjust Access Token / Refresh Token when log out?

Tags: authentication, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I'm developing an authentication system that returns access/refresh tokens when a user logs in. The access token has a short lifetime, whereas the refresh token has a 30 day lifetime.

When a user logs out, I invalidate his access token by adding it to a Redis storage that implements a blacklist. What should I do with his refresh token? It will continue living and the user can access another page after logging out, which results in receiving a new access token. Should I block it with the access token? Because I think that simply removing it from cookies will cause problems because its signature is still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use OAuth 2.0 for user login (especially with refresh token) then it is not the best solution, because public client cannot store securely refresh token (OIDC is preferred).

Back to the question, it depends on business requirements and implementation, if you can still use application after logout for same user context due to refresh token then you should also invalidate refresh token.

To better understand OAuth 2.0 with browser based applications please check this document: https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-10.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Especially for the link you provided me with. I must read this.

Comment: You can also check those links: https://oauth.net/specs/ https://www.scottbrady91.com/oauth/oauth-is-not-authentication, in general OAuth 2.0 is quite complex in terms of correct usage, there are many custom implementations, because OAuth 2.0 was not well defined + his purpose was not to authenticate users.